# Need help please with FBConnect (Facebook iPhone API)

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

I'm using FBConnect in my project.

I would like to commit the whole login and publishing process in an UIWebView instead of the popping window.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir if you want to use UIWebView then you can directly ask the webview to open the page for you via NSURL and NSURLRequest in that case you wont require any sort of API.